# Why does my Eclipse plugin startup fine in one workspace, but not in another?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a plugin for Eclipse and exported it as a JAR file. I put it in the plugins directory of my Eclipse RCP distribution. I then open Eclipse and the plugin functions as expected. I go to my other computer and put the JAR in the plugins directory of the Eclipse RCP distribution and then open Eclipse.

I get messages such as the following in my Error Log:

- Problems encountered starting up plug-in: "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in myplugin.Activator.start() of bundle MyPlugin"
- Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
- Bad extension specification
- startup class must implement org.eclipse.ui.IStartup

Some of those messages confuse me though, because this is what my Activator class looks like:

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin implements IStartup {...
```

It clearly implements IStartup, for instance.

Does anyone have any ideas of what is going on here or at least what direction I should head in to fix this issue?

EDIT

I have now created a new class called StartupClass.java:

```
package myplugin;

import org.eclipse.ui.IStartup;

public class StartupClass implements IStartup {

@Override
public void earlyStartup() 
{

}
}
```

I then changed my plugin.xml to look like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
<startup class="myplugin.StartupClass" />
</extension>
```

Which results in similar errors such as:

- An error occurred while automatically activating bundle MyPlugin
- Plug-in MyPlugin was unable to load class myplugin.StartupClass
- Unable to execute early startup code for an extension

Comment: So, with those changes, do you get the same errors as before?

Comment: Yes, I am getting pretty much the same errors as before.

Comment: Your new errors look different.  In particular, you've got "Plug-in MyPlugin was unable to load class myplugin.StartupClass".  Did you include the `package myplugin;` line in the StartupClass class?

Comment: @zerocrates Yes, the package reference is there, I must not have copied that when I dragged it over here.

Comment: @Treebranch For the record, John Flatness' answer did work for me. You do have to be careful of the code you put in the startup class. For example, the code in it is never run in the display thread, so `Display.getCurrent()` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `org.eclipse.runtime.compatibilty` plugin in one workspace but not the other?

The way you're doing this is deprecated, you should have a separate "startup" class and specify that as the `class` attribute of your `<startup>` element.

From the [Eclipse docs on the startup extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html):

> Do not specify the plug-in class as
>   the value of the class attribute, or
>   it will be instantiated twice (once by
>   regular plug-in activation, and once
>   by this mechanism).
>   If the extension does not provide a
>   class as an attribute on the startup
>   element, the plug-in's activator
>   (plug-in class) must implement
>   org.eclipse.ui.IStartup.
>
> Note that
>   this form is deprecated and should no
>   longer be used. Its functioning relies
>   on the availability of the
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility
>   plug-in and the
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry
>   fragment.

Comment: So you are saying that Activator shouldn't implement IStartup, but instead I should make another class that implements IStartup?

Comment: Yep, and then modify your extension declaration in plugin.xml to refer to that other class (instead of just omitting the `class` attribute altogether, which is what I assume you're doing now).